# Arguments in Hadoop Mapper Class

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am developing a sentiment analysis tool that receives the content from a .txt file and need to check in a dictionary if the word is positive or negative. I use FileInputFormat.addInputPath(args[0]) to reference the .txt file that contain the words to be analyzed. I tried to create an ArrayList with the content of the dictionary (.txt file 64KB) and pass it an static object to a Class ReadDictionary that is used in the Mapper clas. 
Running it on eclipse is ok, but when I try to run on Hadoop I get some errors. How can I pass the content of the dictionary (.txt file 64KB) to map class in a efficient way to run on Hadoop (HDFS)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache` to cache the dictionary file.

DistributedCache is a facility provided by the Map-Reduce framework to cache files (text, archives, jars, etc) needed by applications.

The framework will copy the necessary files on to the slave node before any tasks for the job are executed on that node. Its efficiency stems from the fact that the files are only copied once per job and the ability to cache archives which are un-archived on the slaves.

Here is the [tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html).

Answer (score 0):

In `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper` class, there is a `setup` method, which is called when the `Mapper` is initialized.

You can save your dictionary in HDFS, or locally, or remotely somewhere, and you can pass the handle to it (a path, a filepath, or a remote URL) as a context parameter. In your `setup` impl, you instantiate the dictionary using the context parameter. The dictionary object will stay in memory through the life of your `Mapper`.

You can clean it up, if needed, in the `cleanup` method.